# eth0 static ip at boot

Tags: ethernet, static-ip

I know this gets asked a lot, but none of the answers are working for me.

I have a USB to ethernet dongle on my Windows PC that I would like to connect to a raspberry pi (version 4.14.71-v7+). On the windows side, I have the ethernet adapter set to a static IPv4 address: 169.254.162.135, subnet mask 255.255.255.0, and default gateway 169.254.162.1.

On the raspberry pi, if I type the command `sudo ifconfig eth0 169.254.162.223`, everything works fine, I can ping and connect the two systems.

To make the pi boot with this address automatically, I modified /etc/dhcpcd.conf, adding this to the bottom:

```
interface eth0
static ip_address=169.254.162.223/24
static routers=169.254.162.1
static domain_name_servers=169.254.162.1
```

But this isn't working. Even after rebooting, I just get:

```
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::30ca:fe09:1545:1b84  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether b8:27:eb:ef:d6:df  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 153  bytes 12781 (12.4 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 35  bytes 3963 (3.8 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

And I can't ping from either direction. Running `sudo service dhcpcd status` I get:

```
Nov 04 19:15:32 raspberrypi dhcpcd[518]: eth0: using static address 169.254.162.223/24
Nov 04 19:15:32 raspberrypi dhcpcd[518]: eth0: adding route to 169.254.162.0/24
Nov 04 19:15:32 raspberrypi dhcpcd[518]: eth0: adding default route via 169.254.162.1
Nov 04 19:15:32 raspberrypi dhcpcd[518]: eth0: deleted route to 169.254.162.0/24
Nov 04 19:15:41 raspberrypi dhcpcd[518]: eth0: no IPv6 Routers available
```

FYI, I did *not* modify /etc/network/interfaces, so it is still the default:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)

# Please note that this file is written to be used with dhcpcd
# For static IP, consult /etc/dhcpcd.conf and 'man dhcpcd.conf'

# Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Your config looks good. Educated guess: this is a problem with the fact you are trying to use a link-local subnet (169.254.x.x/24) together with a static configuration in dhcpcd. Try using (say) addresses in 192.168.0.0/24 instead and see if the problem is magically fixed.

Comment: `none of the answers are working for me` .... why not?

Comment: "I can't ping from either direction"

Comment: Is there also a router in addition to the Windows PC and RasPi and does it has the ip address `169.254.162.1`? You should not use this ip range, instead use addresses from e.g. `192.168.1.0/24`.

Answer (score 1):

`169.254.162.223` is a [Link-local address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-local_address) so it is pointless trying to use as a static IPv4 address.

It is even more futile trying to use 169.254.162.1 for a router as Link-local addresses are not routable.

See [How to set up Static IP Address](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/74428/8697)